# A question on efficacy of weblogic portlets

Tags: java, ajax, weblogic, portlet

I am to make a design decision of using either the Weblogic portlets or the Ajax div portlets for developing an application.  Any pointers about the guiding principles?  I am very new to portlet development.

Comment: Don't use weblogic if you can avoid it! You will kick yourself for using weblogic when you're getting constant library conflicts and waiting forever for the server to start.

Comment: Are the Ajax or other porlet technologies good enough?  Are there any other Java portlet technologies that I should study?

Comment: @Steven WebLogic 12c starts in a few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weblogic is not yet JSR 286 compatible,

So in terms of [interoperability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_portal#Enterprise_portal_vendors), Jetspeed or Liferay or JBoss Portal are better choices to start off with. All three are open source.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked and alternative OpenSource portlet Platform (as [Apache JetSpeed](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/))?

It's Open Source and It can be deployed on various servlet contaniers (as Tomcat) and Java EE servers (as Websphere, Weblogic, etc), so you gain portability and vendor independency, relative to Weblogic portlets.